# String literals are truncated using flask in python 3.4

Tags: python, flask

When I run the following simple piece of python / flask I do not get the entire string passed through to the html page - instead of "hello this is simon" I get "hello"
I am working on Python 3.4.2

I thought it might be something to do with encoding but I have tried everything I can think of with encoding and still no joy. Any help gratefully received :)

This is the python file (testit.py)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def init_logon():
    email = "hello this is simon"
    return render_template("testit.html", email=email)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

This is the simple template (testit.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value={{ email }}>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The out put from a number of browsers is all the same: the text is truncated at the first white space

All that is displayed in my browser is:

"hello" - none of the text after the first white space is passed through

apologies I am not allowed to post the image I created :(

Comment: Thank-you :) I have been looking for hours !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your HTML, you didn't quote the attribute value, so the result of your template is

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=hello this is simon>
```

That means only the "hello" is the value of the "value" attribute.  You should be able to see this if you look at the source of the generated page.

You could change your template so it has `value="{{ email }}"`.